# Matching my goal url in Google Analytics with regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex, google-analytics

I want to set user registrations as a goal in Google analytics, but the landing page after registration is different, so I will add a parameter like registration_completed=true

What is the correct regex to use in Google Analytics URL match for this?

So it should contain registration_completed=true and `?` or `&` before it, and `&` , `#` or nothing after it.

```
/registration-completed.html?registration_completed=true
/registration-completed.html?registration_completed=true&message=welcome
/registration-completed.html?message=welcome&registration_completed=true
/registration-completed.html?message=welcome&registration_completed=true#some-anchor
```

Users also land on other pages than `registraton-completed.html`, otherwise I would just use that url for tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^/registration-completed\.html\?([\w&=]*)registration_completed=true([\w&=]*)#?(.*)$
```

Tested with regexr - http://regexr.com?38gl4

**Edit**

To match any page

```
^(.*)\?([\w&=]*)registration_completed=true([\w&=]*)#?(.*)$
```

New regexr - http://regexr.com?38h71

Comment: Maybe I tested incorrectly but it didn't match something like `/contact.html?registration_completed=true`, that first url (e.g contact.html) can be anything.